# Updating an object on realm

Tags: ios, realm

I want to update an object with realm. But my app is crashing.

**My code:**

```
var findConversations = ShufflePerson.objectsWhere("receiver='\(from)'")
var shuf = findConversations[0] as! ShufflePerson
shuf.unreadMessage=shuf.unreadMessage++
self.realm.beginWriteTransaction()
self.realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

**Crash Log:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'
```

How can I fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var findConversations = ShufflePerson.objectsWhere("receiver='\(from)'")
var shuf = findConversations[0] as! ShufflePerson
self.realm.beginWriteTransaction()
shuf.unreadMessage++
self.realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

The issue, as the exception message said, was that you were modifying the object outside of the write transaction. Doing that mutation inside the transaction should do the trick!